# How to get HTML5 Range Slider's value in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a HTML5 Range Slider. We can i send this value to php?
I will send a Email with this value.

HTML:

```
 <div class="unit">
   <div class="slider-group">
        Max value:
   <label id="1-h"></label>
  </div>
  <div id="slider-1-h"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $( '#slider-1-h' ).slider({
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 300,
        value: 99,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( '#1-h' ).html( ui.value );
        }
    });
    $( '#1-h' ).html( $( '#slider-1-h' ).slider( 'value' ) );
});
```

Ok that is fine. And now, we can is send this? I have no input box.
I can`t use $_POST[""] or?

:/

Comment: add a change function to update a hidden form field `change: function( event, ui ) {}`

Comment: what event do you want to use to send it? Is this part of a bigger form or just one control only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the jquery add:

```
change: function(event, ui) {
      $('#sliderValue').attr('value', ui.value);
    }
```

in form add:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sliderValue" id="sliderValue" value="">
```

Comment: so i have a secound question:

Comment: can you help me again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826425/how-to-get-html5-range-2-slides-sliders-value-in-php