# How to get HTML5 Range (2 slides) Slider's value in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="unit">
    <div class="slider-group">
        Budget:
        <label id="2-h"></label>
    </div>
    <div id="slider-2-h"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="sliderBudget" id="sliderValue" value="">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(function() {
    $( '#slider-2-h' ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( '#2-h' ).html( '€' + ui.values[ 0 ] + ' - €' + ui.values[ 1 ] );
        },
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $('#sliderValue').attr('value', ui.value);
        }
    });
    $( '#2-h' ).html('€' + $('#slider-2-h' ).slider( 'values', 0 ) +
                    ' - €' + $( '#slider-2-h' ).slider( 'values', 1 ) );
});
```

But I have a range from - to, and only 1 input (hidden). 
I set now a secound input (hidden) but we can is send the secouund value to the input?

I set a secound:

```
change: function(event, ui){
    $('#sliderValue').attr('value', ui.value);
}
```

with `ui.value[1]` but it's not ok

Comment: How is your question related to PHP?
Is the slider from jQuery UI?

Comment: yes is von jQuery and i have 2 ui.values [0] and ui.values[ 1 ]
and with:
change: function(event, ui) {
            $('#sliderValue').attr('value', ui.value);
        }
can i only set 1 value for the input fild. i need 2

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to achieve your goal is having two input fields.

---

Add another input value with different name.

`<input type="hidden" name="sliderBudget2" id="sliderValue2" value="">`

And alter your `change` event to set the new input value.

```
change: function(event, ui){
    $('#sliderValue').attr('value', ui.value[0]);
    $('#sliderValue2').attr('value', ui.value[1]);
}
```